# How to make a modal slider with next and prev buttons navigation on popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hello so I've been trying to create the next and previous buttons to move the picture when the modal opens up to the next one, I take the pictures like this from WordPress

```
<?php
                        if (!empty($data['images'])):
                            foreach ($data['images'] as $img) : ?>
                                <?php if (!empty($img['image'])) : ?>
                                    <div class="slide parentSlider">
                                        <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
                                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($img['image'], 'carousel-image', '', ['class' => 'img-responsive', 'data-track-content' => '']); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach;
                        endif;
                        ?>
```

This takes all the pictures I got from WordPress and puts them on a column one after another then I added this to create the modal and show the picture when clicked on a popup with a 100% width

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
<!--                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>-->
                                    <img src="" class="imagepreview" id="modal_image" style="width: 100%;" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon">&#10094;</span>
                                </a>
                                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon">&#10095;</span>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Here I'm trying to call the image from the PHP to here through the modal and jQuery

```
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
                //get index for div
                var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
                console.log(idx)
                var id = parseInt(idx);
                $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
                $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
                $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
    });
```

And it shows the picture selected in the modal which is great but it doesn't work to move the picture next or previous one, I tried adding lots of other code I got online but nothing was working here ill attach the codes I tried and didn't work maybe I only implemented them wrong and someone here might know how to do it better

```
// var modalImg = $(".imagepreview");
    // $('.pop').on('click', function() {
    //     $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    //     $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
    //
    // $('.next').on('click',function() {
    //     var curr = $(modalImg).attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    //     var next = $('img[src="' + curr +'"]').parent('div').next().find('img').attr('src');
    //     modalImg.attr('src', next);
    // });
    // $('.prev').on('click',function() {
    //     var curr = $('modalImg').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
    //     var prev = $('img[src="' + curr + '"]').parent('div').prev().find('img').attr('src');
    //     modalImg.attr('src', prev);
    // });
    // });
```

```
//when img is clicked
    // $('.parentSlider-cell img').click(function() {
    //     //get index for div
    //     var idx = $(this).parents('div').index();
    //     console.log(idx)
    //     var id = parseInt(idx);
    //     $('.bd-example-modal-lg').modal('show'); // show the modal
    //     $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
    // });
```

Just wanted a simple next and prev button to move the pics around anything simple will do thank you.

EDIT: For the question in the comments

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators" id="indicators">
                                        <li data-target="#myImg" data-slide-to="0" id="indicator">0</li>
                                        <li data-target="#myImg" data-slide-to="1" id="indicator">1</li>
                                        <li data-target="#myImg" data-slide-to="2" id="indicator">2</li>
                                    </ol>
```

```
$(".carousel-indicators").on('click', function(){

            let dataslide = $("#indicators").find(`[data-slide='${id}']`).index(this);
            //let dataslide = $("#indicators").find("data-slide").index(this); //Used this too but same result
            
            // let dsxid = dataslide.index(); - was testing with this
            // dsid = parseInt(dsxid) - testing
            console.log(dataslide);
            if(id === dataslide){
                let next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
                $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image);
                $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
                $(".carousel-indicators").find("li[data-slide-to="+id+"]").addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            }
            // console.log(id);
        });
```

I think I got very close with making the buttons because without the index part it returns an array that shows the button for each image I'm at that time so I wanted to turn it into an index and all it as an id so that I can compare if the id is the same on click and then if not change picture or some logic like that but the index keeps returning -1 i tried to do a .filter and other code but without the id inside the data-slide but it wasn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare global variable which will have `index` of the current `.pop` class which is selected by user so everytime you click on next button you need to first **increment** this index and then get the particular div at that position and using `find()` get the `image` src and add same to your `imagepreview`.

Same you can do to `prev` button just you need to **decrement** index value by `1` and then use this value to get `src` of image and apply same to your `imagepreview` div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var id;
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).parent().index();
  id = parseInt(idx);
  $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
  $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  id++; //increment
  if (id < $('.imgs').length) {
    //get id find src
    var next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image); //add same
    $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
  }
});
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  id--; //decremnt
  if (id > -1) {
    //find image
    var next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image); //add same
    $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--addd this-->
<div class="outer">
  <!--add imgs class-->
  <div class="slide parentSlider imgs">
    <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=One" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide parentSlider imgs">
    <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=two" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide parentSlider imgs">
    <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fcf00c/000&text=Three" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <!--                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>-->
              <img src="" class="imagepreview" id="modal_image" style="width: 100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon">&#10094;</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon">&#10095;</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly well except one part, it keeps increasing when I keep clicking next and when I have to go back I need to go as many times as it increased should I add an if statement that checks the length of the images so that it never exceeds that seems something I can do on my own so thank you a lot for this

Comment: Hey was wondering if you know how I can use this code you showed to add the same function but in bullets under the carousel?

Comment: bullets under carousel? Please elaborate more :)

Comment: Im sorry for not explaining well, what I meant was something like this https://imgur.com/t3IWqoY
The circles under a slider that when you click on a certain one it would open that photo for  example like in my case it if I click the first one it would open id 1 if I click the second id 2 but how can I do it more dynamically? sorry if I'm confusing I added a picture hope that makes my "try" to explain it better

Comment: Hi this structure will be more easy if you can put that php code for displaying images inside modal . So, onclick event will be same and prev and next will automatically handle by your slider.Also look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/abbasarezoo/pen/NbJrqj)

Comment: Thanks ill try to do that then i thought i should also add the php code there so ill try to see how it works with wordpress like that

Comment: Hello, so I was looking upon something and got some ideas from people, they said to use an Array would be better maybe and call from the array with jQuery to show the ID at the same time by the code you provided so like this 
`let imagesArray = $('.myImg').map(function(){ return this.src; }).get();`
Then use that to change 
`$(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);`

What I can't figure it out is how to use it to call on HTML with something like this
`<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#modal_image" data-slide-to="0" class="active">0</li>`

Comment: Can I use something like this to iterate the array but instead of logging the ID to call it repeating on the HTML? 
`$( "#slider ul li img" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $(this).src() );
});`

Comment: Your `data-slide-to` has value `0,1.. ?` why not use something like this `$(".carousel-indicators").find("li[data-slide-to="+id+"]").addClass("active")` ? where id is img position.which you already get on click .

Comment: I updated the thread since its more code but what do you think about it

Answer (score 0):

```js
var id;
$('.pop').on('click', function() {
  var idx = $(this).parent().index();
  id = parseInt(idx);
  $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
  $('#imagemodal').modal('show');
  $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id); // slide carousel to selected
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  id++; //increment
  if (id < $('.imgs').length) {
    //get id find src
    var next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image); //add same
    $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
  }
});
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  id--; //decremnt
  if (id > -1) {
    //find image
    var next_image = $('.imgs').eq(id).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.imagepreview').attr('src', next_image); //add same
    $(".carousel-inner").carousel(id);
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--addd this-->
<div class="outer">
  <!--add imgs class-->
  <div class="slide parentSlider imgs">
    <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=One" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide parentSlider imgs">
    <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/555/000&text=two" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide parentSlider imgs">
    <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600/fcf00c/000&text=Three" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <!--                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>-->
              <img src="" class="imagepreview" id="modal_image" style="width: 100%;">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon">&#10094;</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon">&#10095;</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.